# Find areas in discrete data, which can be approximated by lines

Tags: matlab, math

I have a discrete function y(n), n=1..8000 with two areas, which can be approximated by almost horizontal straight lines as shown in image.
[image]

I'd like to find coordinates x1, x2 of points where these areas meet the rapidly growing part of function. In Matlab, y(n) is a one-dimensional vector.

Comment: What assumptions can you make about the data? Will there always be two flat parts? Can there be small spikes in the flat parts? Is there a minimum guaranteed size of the flat parts?

Comment: Yes, two flat parts will be always, without any spikes and their slope will be small compared to the slope of steep part. The minimum size of the flat parts is approximately 600. [Here](https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B3Qk7GruY7uma2Q0Wk1WbnY3T0k&export=download) , I saved variable y into mat file.

Comment: You should take a look at the derivative (```diff```). It will be (approximately) zero in the flat parts and at x1 and x2 it will suddenly change strongly. You can then use ```findpeaks``` to locate these peaks. It will probably require some user-specified threshold as to distinguish the actual peaks from noise or the slight changes in slope. You could automate this too but I'm not sure if it is worth the trouble.

Comment: In that case, I'd do a histogram of the y-values first to get a rough estimate of the cutoff value of the flat parts, and then perform a robust regression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If data set is very smooth, you can use simple derivative magnitude detector.

If some noise peaks and small false fronts are possible, you'd better to use more robust method, for example

Choose some initial value for x1 (for example, 600)
Calculate linear regression parameters `y = a*x + b` for range 1..x1
If slope parameter `a` is small enough, increase x1 and repeat calculation
if slope is larger than some reasonable threshold, decrease x1 and repeat.

Binary search algorithm is rather quick way to reach needed x1 value.

Do the same for x2..N range.

Comment: I've tried this method and it worked. Although, as PatronBernard and RPM mentioned, the derivative is more prominent, than data. So, I calculated regression parameters for gradient(y).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @PatronBernard, you could look at the derivative of your trace, knowing that the derivative deviates from zero once you are no longer in the flat bit. This would involve manually picking a threshold which might have to be done for each new trace, and would be sensitive to noise in your trace. Here is an implementation, also showing the issues you might get with a noisy trace:

```
threshold = 0.2;
y1 = diff(y)/(x(2) - x(1));
y2 = diff(y1)/(x(2) - x(1));

figure;
hold on
plot(x,y, 'b')
xi = find(y1>threshold,1);
line([x(xi) x(xi)], ylim, 'Color', 'r')
xi = find(flipud(y1)>threshold,1);
line([x(length(x) - xi + 1) x(length(x) - xi + 1)], ylim, 'Color', 'r')
```

[image: Derivative approach]

Alternatively, if you have genuinely noisy data I would recommend looking at IEC standard 60469:2013 "Transitions, Pulses and Related Waveforms - Terms, Definitions and Algorithms".